# Deducing the locus of a point of intersection of two lines.

Tags: analytic-geometry, problem-solving, locus

> A straight line $L$ through origin meets $x+y=1$...$(1)$ at $P$ and $x+y=3$...$(2)$ at $Q$. Through $P$ and $Q$ two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ are drawn which are parallel to $2x-y=5$...$(3)$ and $3x-y=5$...$(4)$ respectively. $L_1$ and $L_2$ intersect at $R$. Show that the locus of $R$ as $L$ varies is a straight line.

The solution :

Let $L$ be $y=mx$.
Using $(1)$&$(2)$ we get $P$ = $(\frac{1}{m+1},\frac{m}{m+1})$ and $Q$ = $(\frac{3}{m+1},\frac{3m}{m+1})$.

Now, $L_1$ is $y-2x = \frac{m-2}{m+1}$...$(5)$ and $L_2$ is $y+3x=\frac{3m+9}{m+1}...$(6)

Eliminate $m$ from $(5)$ and $(6)$ which gives us the locus of $R$ as $x-3y+5=0$ which represents a straight line.

**My Question** : I understand that $L_1 + \lambda(L_2) = 0$ represents the set of straight lines passing through the intersection of the two lines (including the line representing the locus of $R$, but I don't understand how the value for $\lambda$ using which $m$ is eliminated also gives us the equation representing the line which is the locus of $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, $L_1$ is $y-2x = \frac{m-2}{m+1}$ and $L_2$ is $y+3x=\frac{3m+9}{m+1}$. At the intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$, 
$$
2x+\frac{m-2}{m+1}=-3x+\frac{3m+9}{m+1}.
$$
So,
$$
5x=\frac{3m+9}{m+1}-\frac{m-2}{m+1}=\frac{2m+11}{m+1}.\\
5xm+5x=2m+11\\
(5x-2)m=11-5x\\
m=\frac{11-5x}{5x-2}.
$$
Substituting into (5) gives
$$
y-2x=\frac{\frac{11-5x}{5x-2}-2}{\frac{11-5x}{5x-2}+1}=\frac{11-5x-10x+4}{11-5x+5x-2}=\frac{15-15x}{9}=\frac{5-5x}{3}\\
3y-6x=5-5x\\
x-3y+5=0
$$
as required.

The main idea is NOT to try to find a value of $\lambda$ as posted in your question. We can say that the equation of the locus is $L_1 + \lambda(L_2) = 0$ ONLY IF we already know it is a straight line. However, you cannot assume it is a straight line, because the question is asking you to **prove** that it is a straight line.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by, "the main idea is NOT to try to find a value of $\lambda$...", why is this so? Also, why does eliminating $m$ give the required equation? The problem states that the locus is a straight line that is why I assumed it to be...

Comment: @JC2000 The question is asking you to SHOW that it is a straight line. It is something you have to PROVE. So, even though the question says it is straight, you CANNOT assume it is straight. You also cannot use the formula $L_1+\lambda L_2=0$, because this is for finding the equation of a straight line, and you cannot use $L_1+\lambda L_2=0$ until you have PROVED that the locus is a straight line.

Comment: I see, now I understand why you cannot use that particular equation. Could you also explain why eliminating $m$ gives the required equation?

Comment: @JC2000 I have shown you how to do this in my answer

Comment: I am not sure if I am being clear or a bit dense but I seem to have understood the process by which $m$ can be eliminated but I am struggling to understand how we know that the result obtained is the required equation? My guess is that since the equation that represents the solution (i.e intersection) of the two lines always represents $R$. Is this correct? Apologies if this question is daft.

Comment: Is it that if the equations of the lines stood for unique lines, then the solution would have been the coordinates of $R$ for that set of linear equations. In this case, the equations represent a set of possible lines and hence the solution is the set of possible coordinates of $R$, which in other words is the equation representing the locus of $R$?

Comment: @JC2000 Yes you are right